# Mathematical Expression of Quality Parametized by Circle

Tags: calculus, notation

I have a 2D scalar map $Q$ of quality. The quality content $Q_c$ is basically summation of the quality values inside a region, say a circle, or a rectangle or any other shape. I want to write an expression that parametizes this quality content by center of the circle and radius, so obviously a larger circle will inscribe more quality and will have more quality content. How can I write an expression that states $Q_c$ in terms of $R$ and $c$ is the following correct?

$$Q_c=\sum_{r=0}^{R} Q(r,c)$$

---

Looks like the expression is not correct. What would be the correct expression for this scenario?

Comment: I take it that all your possible radius-values are integers? Otherwise that sum doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, not integers but they are discrete and not continuous.

Comment: Then the sum, as written, still makes no sense. What idea are you trying to express with that sum?

Comment: @JohnHughes So assuming there is a quality map/grid discretized by interval 0.1 so x-axis/y-axis (0,0.1,0.2..),now if I lay a cricle anywhere on that grid then determining the quality content is merely summing up all the quality inside the map. So all the nodes of the grid falling inside the circle must be summed up to determine the quality content inside the circle parametized by some radius and center. The nodes on the grid tells us the quality value so an example of such scalar map is Q=5 at (0.2,0.5) but I want to parametize it by circle parameters with expression and not formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your summary in the comment says that you're looking for a general expressions for a sum all entries that lie on a circle within a grid with spacing $0.1$. You can make life easier if you define
$$
H(i, j) = Q(i/10, j/10)
$$
where $Q$ is your quality function. Now $H$ is defined for integers, rather then one-tenth-integers. And to express the quantity you're looking for in terms of $R$, you have
$$
S(R) = \sum{i^2 + j^2 \le 10R} H(i, j)
$$
for which you'd like a general expression.

Now suppose that I have any sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$ of real numbers, you pick your quality function so that
$$
H(i, j) = \begin{cases} a_i & j = 0, i \ge 0 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Then it'll turn out that $S(R)$ is just the $R$th partial sum of the series
$$
a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots
$$

So your problem is *at least as hard* as finding an expression for the partial sums of an arbitrary series, which I think we may safely call "difficult".

In short: there's no easy way to do this.

Comment: I think I understood and maybe even got a hint how can i do it so the set of equations for a circle centered at $c_x,c_y$ with radius $R$ to be solved is as follows: $$S(c_x,c_y,R) = \sum H(i, j)$$ s.t. $$i^2 + j^2 \le 10R$$, $$c_x<i<R ,c_y<j<R$$ Please do let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: So the above would be quadratic programming and we can further impose constraints on i to take rational values. Is this understanding of mine correct?

Comment: This makes no sense to me, but I don't do anything with optimization or quadratic programming, so it might make more sense to others. Perhaps one of them can jump in and offer something. I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the response. Its just constraint optimization so the first equation is the objective that we want to sum up all the quality to know total quality content. Now this objective alone would be full map space, thus we  want to collapse this space to a circle by limiting the values $i$ and $j$ can take given by second and third equation. I was able to work this out by looking at your equations.